# apt-get remove geoclue-2.0 made Gnome desktop with all its dependencies gone

Tags: gnome, package-management, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, geolocation

Tried to remove some packages, instead deleted some important files.
Did the following
**
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge redshift

Sudo apt-get remove geoclue-2.0
**
Not able to add images from phone,so i will just specify what happened

**The second command removed
Gnome(calendar, control center,update manager,gir1.2 geoclue ),Ubuntu session, Ubuntu desktop, Ubuntu settings daemon,gnome-tweaks ,tools,shell
Would like to know if there's a solution to this or will have to go for a fresh install?

I have a  copy of home directory in another portable hdd.

Would like to know if i can upgrade to Ubuntu 20.0 from ubuntu recovery mode and fix these problems.

Please let me know if i can do anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

This should get your desktop back to normal:

```
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-session gdm3
```

Regarding other applications such as Calendar and Tweaks, you will need to reinstall those.

Comment: Ran above cmd  with sudo , it says package Ubuntu-session is not available , but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing ,has been obsolete or is only available from another source, However following package replace it uniity session..... Package Ubuntu-desktop has no installation candidate

Comment: That doesn't sound right. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you type the package name correctly, all lower case: `ubuntu-session` ?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.  ,yes all lowercase

Comment: `ubuntu-session` is definitely a package in 18.04. I wonder if your apt sources are messed up? What is the output of `apt search ubuntu-session` ?